# Nvidia Card with 2010 Mac Pro

Tags: macos, mac, video

I am a video editor and would like to take advantage of the new Mercury Playback Engine on Premiere CS5, but it can only use nvidia cards, and I don't want to spend $2000 on a Quadro card.

Can I use a gtx 200 series card in the most recent Mac Pros? i.e. the Mac Pro's that are currently for sale on apple.com.

I can't find a cheap mac GTX 285.

Comment: Are you shopping for a 200 mac series card or asking if a 200 series card can be used with Premiere CS5 and the Mercury Playback Engine?

Comment: i'm wondering if the normal geforce cards will work in the Mac Pro. They would be the PC version, but there are mac drivers on the Nvidia site. I know the 200 series cards can be used for PPro CS5, I use them on the PC side, but I'm curious if I can put them into the mac. I don't want to go broke getting a quadro card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially, the PC variants of the Nvidia cards will not work in any of the mac pros under OS X.  The mac versions of the nvidia cards have mac specific boot instructions for OS X operation.  You could add a PC variant of a nvidia video card to a mac pro, but it would only be useable by default under boot camp/windows.  I believe the GTX 285 mac version was the only 200 series card produced for macs, so that may be your only option.

Unofficially, there are people that have attempted to flash similar Nvidia cards for the mac platform and have gotten specific models to work to some degree.  This is obviously not supported by apple.  I am just saying it is technically possible with some specific cards. You need specific models with specific sizes of memory.  This comes with the risk of bricking video cards (incorrect flash, errors, etc.), boot issues, and various other inconsistencies with using unsupported hardware in apple machines.  You can google for various mac/pc video card flashing information sites around the web that discuss user success and failure experiences.